# Username recovery code not working as expected

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, validation

I am working on a site for the company I work for. It requires users register and log in. All of the data is stored on SQL database. I am trying to add a "Lost Username' form for username recovery via email. Now... I am not a coder. I am just a rather gifted code skimmer. I have successfully completed everything they have asked, except for this, and cannot quite figure out why it is not working. I figured it was time to seek out some help.

Here is the code from my controller:

```
        function forgot_pass(){

          $data['page_title']=" Forgot Password ";
          $data['item']="Password";

          // initializing db keys
          $data['table_name'] ="physicians";
          $data['primary_key_name']="physician_id";

           //BOF Edit physician
           if( isset( $_REQUEST['physician_forgot_pass'] ) ){

              if ($this->form_validation->run('physician_forgot_pass'))
              {
                $physician_row=$this->model_site->check_physcian_retrive_password( $_REQUEST['username'],  encode_decode($_REQUEST['email'],'encode')  );
                //echo "<pre />"; print_r($physician_row); die;
                if($physician_row){

                    $physician_exist=1;

                    if($physician_row['approved']==1){ 

                       //Generate new Randmo password
                       $this->load->helper( 'get_random_password' );
                       $new_password=get_random_password(); //echo $new_password; die;

                       $update_data=array(
                                        'password'   => md5($new_password)
                                      );
                       $this->model_site->update_table('physicians', $update_data, 'username', $_REQUEST['username']  );


                       $this->load->helper( 'email_send' );

                       //GET SENDER EMAIL ADDRESS
                       $data['email_data']=$this->model_cms->get_single_record( 'email', 'email_id', 1 );
                       //echo "<pre />"; print_r($data['email_data']); die;

                       //Sending Mail To Physician
                       $physician_email = encode_decode($physician_row['email'],'decode');

                       $data['physician_email_msg']="Your New Password is ".$new_password;
                       $data['email_sent']=email_send( $data['email_data']['email'], $data['email_data']['email_name'], $physician_email  , "Retrive Password", $data['physician_email_msg']);
                       if($data['email_sent']){
                              $data['status']=1;
                              $data['status_message']="Your password has been sent to your mail at ".$physician_email;
                              $data['notification']=  array(
                                                        "notify_type"  => "notify_site_success",
                                                        "notify_message"   => $data['status_message']
                                                     );

                              //insert to audit log table
                              $audit_log_details="Physician <b>".encode_decode($physician_row['name'],'decode')."</b> ( Username : <b>".$physician_row['username']."</b> ) requested for retrieving lost passwords. A new password was sent to Physician. Email Address of the Physician is  <i>".$physician_email."</i> . ";
                              $audit_log_id = $this->model_cms->add_audit_log_record( $physician_row['physician_id'] , $physician_row['username'] , 'physician', "Retrieving lost passwords request ", $audit_log_details, time() );

                              $data['nbc_email_msg']=$audit_log_details."Here is the email below \n Your New Password is ".$new_password;
                              $data['email_sent']=email_send( $data['email_data']['email'], $data['email_data']['email_name'], $data['email_data']['email'], "Retrive Password", $data['nbc_email_msg']);
                       }
                       else {
                          $data['status']=0;
                          $data['status_message']="Error in sending mail to National Biological Corporation. Please try again later";
                          $data['notification']=  array(
                                                    "notify_type"  => "notify_site_error",
                                                    "notify_message"   => $data['status_message']
                                                 );
                       }

                    }
                    else {
                         $data['status']=0;
                         $data['status_message']="Your account is not approved yet. you will be able to request for retrive password after your account is approved.";
                         $data['notification']=  array(
                                                    "notify_type"  => "notify_site_error",
                                                    "notify_message"   => $data['status_message']
                                                 );
                    }
                }
                else {
                         $data['status']=0;
                         $data['status_message']="Sorry! Could not found physcian with this username and email.";
                         $data['notification']=  array(
                                                    "notify_type"  => "notify_site_error",
                                                    "notify_message"   => $data['status_message']
                                                 );
                }
              }
            }
           //EOF Edit physician

          $this->load->view('site/view_header',$data);
          $this->load->view('site/view_left_panel',$data);
          $this->load->view('site/view_physician_forgot_password',$data);
          $this->load->view('site/view_footer');
    }

    function forgot_userid(){

          $data['page_title']=" Forgot Username ";
          $data['item']="Username";

          // initializing db keys
          $data['table_name'] ="physicians";
          $data['primary_key_name']="physician_id";

           //BOF Edit physician
           if( isset( $_REQUEST['physician_forgot_userid'] ) ){

              if ($this->form_validation->run('physician_forgot_userid'))
              {
                $physician_row=$this->model_site->check_physician_get_userid( $_REQUEST['dea_number'],  encode_decode($_REQUEST['email'],'encode')  );
                //echo "<pre />"; print_r($physician_row); die;
                if($physician_row){

                    $physician_exist=1;

                    if($physician_row['approved']==1){ 

                        $this->load->helper( 'email_send' );

                       //GET SENDER EMAIL ADDRESS
                       $data['email_data']=$this->model_cms->get_single_record( 'email', 'email_id', 1 );
                       //echo "<pre />"; print_r($data['email_data']); die;

                       //Sending Mail To Physician
                       $physician_email = encode_decode($physician_row['email'],'decode');

                       $data['physician_email_msg']="According to our records, your registered username is ".$physician_row['username'];
                       $data['email_sent']=email_send( $data['email_data']['email'], $data['email_data']['email_name'], $physician_email  , "Your requested username reminder from phototherapydoctor.com", $data['physician_email_msg']);
                       if($data['email_sent']){
                              $data['status']=1;
                              $data['status_message']="Your username has been sent to your mail at ".$physician_email;
                              $data['notification']=  array(
                                                        "notify_type"  => "notify_site_success",
                                                        "notify_message"   => $data['status_message']
                                                     );

                              //insert to audit log table
                              $audit_log_details="Physician <b>".encode_decode($physician_row['name'],'decode')."</b> ( Username : <b>".$physician_row['username']."</b> ) requested for retrieving lost passwords. A new password was sent to Physician. Email Address of the Physician is  <i>".$physician_email."</i> . ";
                              $audit_log_id = $this->model_cms->add_audit_log_record( $physician_row['physician_id'] , $physician_row['username'] , 'physician', "Retrieving lost passwords request ", $audit_log_details, time() );

                              $data['nbc_email_msg']=$audit_log_details."Here is the email below \n Your New Password is ".$physician_row['username'];
                              $data['email_sent']=email_send( $data['email_data']['email'], $data['email_data']['email_name'], $data['email_data']['email'], "Retrive Password", $data['nbc_email_msg']);
                       }
                       else {
                          $data['status']=0;
                          $data['status_message']="Error in sending mail to National Biological Corporation. Please try again later";
                          $data['notification']=  array(
                                                    "notify_type"  => "notify_site_error",
                                                    "notify_message"   => $data['status_message']
                                                 );
                       }

                    }
                    else {
                         $data['status']=0;
                         $data['status_message']="Your account is not approved yet. You will be able to request username after your account is approved.";
                         $data['notification']=  array(
                                                    "notify_type"  => "notify_site_error",
                                                    "notify_message"   => $data['status_message']
                                                 );
                    }
                }
                else {
                         $data['status']=0;
                         $data['status_message']="Sorry! We could not find a physician with this DEA number and email.";
                         $data['notification']=  array(
                                                    "notify_type"  => "notify_site_error",
                                                    "notify_message"   => $data['status_message']
                                                 );
                }
              }
            }
           //EOF Edit physician

          $this->load->view('site/view_header',$data);
          $this->load->view('site/view_left_panel',$data);
          $this->load->view('site/view_physician_forgot_userid',$data);
          $this->load->view('site/view_footer');
    }
```

Here is the chunk from my model...:

```
  function check_physician_get_userid( $dea_number, $email ) {  //check if physcian exist with this dea number and password

    $query = $this->db->get_where( "physicians", array( "dea_number" => $dea_number , "email" => $email ) ) ;

    if( $query->num_rows() > 0 ) {
        return $query->row_array();
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }

} //end check_physcian_retrive_userid
```

Here is my form_validation entry:

```
                  'physician_forgot_userid'=> array(
                               array(
                                        'field' => 'dea_number',
                                        'label' => 'DEA Number',
                                        'rules' => 'required'
                                     ),
                               array(
                                        'field' => 'email',
                                        'label' => 'Email',
                                        'rules' => 'required|valid_email'
                                     )
                                ),
```

And finally, My view:

```
<div class="middle_panel">

 <p style="color:#424A8D;font-family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:15pt;font-weight:bold;">Retrieve Lost Username</p>

 <div class="physician_join_form">

    <?php echo  form_open('physician/forgot_userid'); ?>

       <div class="register_box_text">DEA Number : </div>
       <div class="register_box_field">
         <input name="dea_number" id="dea_number" value="<?php echo set_value('dea_number'); ?>" type="dea_number" size="20">
         <?php echo form_error('dea_number'); ?>
       </div>

       <div class="register_box_text">Email : </div>
       <div class="register_box_field">
         <input name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo set_value('email'); ?>" type="email" size="20">
         <?php echo form_error('email'); ?>
       </div>

       <div class="register_box_text" style="background:#F9F9F9;"> &nbsp; </div>
       <div class="register_box_field">
          <input type="submit" id="physician_forgot_userid" name="physician_forgot_userid" value="Submit">
       </div>

    <?php echo form_close(); ?>

 </div>
```

Comment: are u getting any error???

Comment: what do you mean by `All of the data is stored on _SQL_ database`?

Comment: Nope, not any php errors. just a site error saying no user with this dea number and email...

Comment: Just saying that it is on a SQL database. Not sure what value that  info may have. Just thought I'd mention it. Everything else works.

Comment: I do know this, I change 'userid' to 'password' in the following line, it works, but wrong. It requires you ENTER your username. Then it will email your username to you from the database...                    $physician_row=$this->model_site->check_physician_get_userid

Comment: encode_decode() is an helper function is it???

Comment: While storing email in database are you encoding it???

Comment: Yes, it is encoded. But, the email field is not the one causing the issue. It is the dea_number field. This function was 'cloned' so to speak, from the 'Recover Password' section of the site. As I said above, if I swap out 'userid' for 'password' it then works with your username in the dea number field. When subitting the form in this way, it does indeed query the database and email the requested username. It just doesn't like the input of the dea number. - En Route to work, back on in about 30 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In your views: change the input type of DEA Number field to a valid input type: [This is not going to solve your problem though.]

> **type="dea_number"**
>
> Just write a separate function and model which fetches all details from `physicians` table.
>
> **Controller:** Inside your present Controller.

```
    function fetch_details_ctrl($dea_number) {
           if(!empty($dea_number)) {
               $result = $this->model_cms->fetch_details_model($dea_number);
               print_r($result);
           }
           else
               echo 'Pls. provide a DEA NUMBER';
    }
```

**Model:** Inside models/model_cms.php

```
    function fetch_details_model($dea_number) {
       $query = $this->db->get_where("physicians",array("dea_number"=>$dea_number));
       if( $query->num_rows() > 0 ) {
           return $query->row_array();
       }
       else {
           return false;
       }
    }
```

Call the controller function like this: **http://{YOURSITE}.com/{CONTROLLER_NAME}/fetch_details_ctrl/[DEA_NUMBER]**

DEA_NUMBER should be the one that an user 'll enter in the input field provided in the recovery View. 
If this produces result, it means the problem is not exactly with dea number. If doesn't, there can be two reasons:
1. The DEA Number that user enters is not existing in database.
<strike>2. There's some problem with Email address encryption, But you clearly said that its working correctly the other way [Forgot Password]. But I've not seen that code so I still have that doubt.</strike>

Comment: Thank You! I shall certainly try this shortly and will update then. I appreciate your attention and assistance.

Comment: Ok, so I tries this with no results. Although, it is highly likely that I did something wrong. Am I supposed to add this to my current model & controller or create new separate ones? I really have no idea what I am doing beyond general editing. I do know that the person that did the original build/design had a tendency to customize things a bit off standard. Also, if it provides any insight, this site is sort of 'split' between what the public can see and the content management system. Two models and two sets of views, model_site and model_cms. Everything else appears to be shared.

Comment: That's quite a lot of comment...! I've edited my Answer. If it's still not helping you I'll still be glad to help U...

Comment: Firstly, I do REALLY appreciate all of the attention your paying my issues. I tried what you described to the best of understanding and ability with no luck, although, I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "Call the controller function like this". I am learning most of this as I go along and feel like I should/need to know what that means in more detail. I edited my Q and added the password portion of the code for review.

Comment: "Call the controller function like this:" means the URL that you have to type on browser address bar is the one that I've entered on the top. Now after checking your retrieve password code, the 2nd point is ruled out. The problem is surely with DEA Number!The number that you enter might not be existing in database/It might be stored in different format.

Comment: WOOO! It was the encode_decode! It wasn't seeing it in the database in it's decoded format. I added 'encode_decode' and the closing 'encode' and it kicked right in! Thanks for all of your help. I don't think I would have tried that if you hadn't mentioned "It might be stored in another format". (cheers wildly)

Comment: Kewl... :) Happy for u... :)